# How to get my code out of SVN conflicted files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I know, If multiple developers works on same file, conflict occurs. I have worked on NoName.js file. Later someone worked on the files. Now, I see the files:

```
NoName.js

NoName.js.mine

NoName.js.r11143

NoName.js.r11153
```

Which file contains code worked by me ?

Comment: Please see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve and http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html#tsvn-dug-conflicts-file) and [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve) chapters that cover your question.

The file that contains your code (i.e. the code that existed in your working copy before you `svn update`) is **`NoName.js.mine`**

From [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html#tsvn-dug-conflicts-file):

> **filename.ext.mine**
>
> This is your file as it existed in your working copy before you
>   updated your working copy - that is, without conflict markers. This
>   file has your latest changes in it and nothing else.